# Cannot figure out SQL SUM() with a WHERE

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get a result from SQL database, and I want it to get a ratio and sort it by that ratio. That is number of rows where the value is yes and costumerid is the same, divided by the total number of rows with the costumerid, and ORDER BY that ratio. This is what I have at the moment:

```
 $sqlsortby = "SELECT DISTINCT q2, q14,
               (SUM(WHERE costumerid='$costumerid' AND option1='yes') / 
                SUM(WHERE costumerid='$costumerid')) AS costumerratio
               FROM costumers
               WHERE q14='successful' AND ordernum='$ordernumsession'
               ORDER BY costumerratio";
```

Thanks :)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  q2   |  costumerid  |  option1  |  ordernum  |  q14      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  Bob  |       1      |  yes      | 001        | successful|
|  Bob  |       1      |  no       | 002        | successful|
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: how many records will be filtered against ordernum? 1 or more than 1?

Comment: @Augwa What do you mean?

Comment: how did you arrive with that sql statement?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I just did it thinking this was the way to do it

Comment: I don't see what `q2` is doing in the select statement.  Can you show us what output you expect here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen q2 is the costumer name

Comment: Do you understand that `SUM()` is an aggregate function, and that, as you have written it, will probably return a single row?

Comment: Please modify your question to show your table names and each table's structure.  The provision of sample data and desired output would also improve the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I didn't know that

Comment: and  @TimBiegeleisen can you actually sum and where clause? i think this guy is just getting away from his homework.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUM()` without `GROUP BY` as you currently have probably is not what you want, because it will return just a single record in the result set.  More typically, we use `SUM()` with `GROUP BY`.  Here is my guess as to what you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT q2, q14,
           SUM(CASE WHEN costumerid='$costumerid' AND option1='yes'
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
           SUM(CASE WHEN costumerid='$costumerid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS costumerratio
    FROM costumers
    WHERE q14='successful' AND
          ordernum='$ordernumsession'
    GROUP BY q2, q14
) t
ORDER BY t.costumerratio
```

Also note that the code you were using inside `SUM()` to aggregate was broken.  Instead, I have replaced it with `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, I think this is the simplest way to do what you want:

```
SELECT q2, q14, AVG(option1 = 'yes') as costumerratio
FROM costumers
WHERE q14 = 'successful' AND ordernum = '$ordernumsession' AND
      costumerid = '$costumerid'
GROUP BY q2, q14
ORDER BY costumerratio;
```

You can do essentially the same thing in other databases, but it requires `CASE`.

Note that this assumes that you want rows where `customerid = $costumerid`.